# Simple singularities of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-fields, singularity-theory

Let $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ a compact and orientable hypersurface of even dimension, with Gauss map $\gamma : M \to S^n$, that is, $\gamma(p)$ is normal to $M$ at $p \in M$. Let $a, b \in S^n$ be antipodal points that are regular values for $\gamma$. Since $n$ is even, there exists a vector field $u$ on the sphere that has exactly $a$ and $b$ as singularities, each one with index 1. Now define a vector field $v$ on $M$ by $v(p) = u(\gamma(p))$. This makes sense if we identify $T_p M$ with $T_{\gamma(p)} S^n$. Then the singularities of $v$ are the points in $\gamma^{-1}(a) \cup \gamma^{-1}(b) = \{a_1, \dots, a_r \} \cup \{ b_1, \dots, b_s \}$.

The fact that $a$ and $b$ are regular values imply that $\gamma$ is a diffeomorphism on a neighbourhood of these points. Why does that imply that they are simple singularities of $v$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's your definition of a simple singularity of a mapping $f\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$? Is it not that the derivative is nonsingular at the point?

Comment: For $v$ a vector field defined on a manifold $N$, $p$ is a simple singularity if $det (\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}) \neq 0$ at p, where $a_i$ are such that $v(q) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(q) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i}(\varphi^{-1}(q))$, and $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to N$ is a parametrization of $N$ around $q$.

Comment: Nonsingular derivative matrix is the same as the derivative matrix having nonzero determinant. (And at a *zero* of a vector field, this criterion is independent of local coordinates on your manifold.)